# How to exclude some algorithms for \listofalgorithms

Tags: table-of-contents, captions, algorithms, algorithm2e

I tried with `\captionsetup{list=no}` but it doesn't work for the algorithm listing. Any ideas? I am splitting alg. over several pages using `algorithm2e` and don't want the captions of the split algorithms to show.

```
\begin{algorithm}[ht]
\caption*{MyAlgorithm}
\captionsetup{list=no}
\label{alg:myalg2}
\end{algorithm}
```

Right now the dots are showing without the name, i wan't to get rid of the dots.

Thanks.

Comment: Instead of `\captionsetup`, add `\renewcommand{\addcontentsline}[3]{}` *before* using `\caption*`.

Comment: @Werner thanks a lot this worked great. Post is as an answer and I'll accept it :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `\captionsetup`, add `\renewcommand{\addcontentsline}[3]{}` *before* using `\caption*`. This de-activates the write-to-ToC functionality. Since it's executed inside a group (the `algorithm` environment), the change will be local.